# Define column name dynamically by current date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT  
    ProjectId, 
    ProjectName,               
    D3 as "three month ago",
    D2 as "two month ago",
    D1 as "last month",
    F0 as "current month",
    F1 as "next month",
    F2 as "next two month",        
FROM
    View_Year_Forcast
```

I want to specify the column name according to the current month.

I have a function `get_month_name` that gets the month symbol like (d1,d2,d3,f0..) and return a string that represent the month name in Hebrew.

What is the best way to solve the problem?

*Just for the record I am trying to do this in a stored procedure in SQL Server*

Comment: You cannot do this in T-SQL - your best bet would bet to return the values as you have them in your query now, and **additionally** return the spelled out month names for each of those six months. Let the frontend (web app or whatever) handle the actual display using the month names instead of the column names

Answer (score 2):

It *is* possible to do this with dynamic SQL:

```
declare @month nvarchar(50)
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

set @month = 'March' -- execute your `get_month_name` function here instead

set @sql = 'select D3 as ' + @month + ' from View_Year_Forcast'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

However, dynamic SQL has its issues. See [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for an in-depth explanation.

So if it's somehow possible, I would rather **not** use dynamic SQL, but do something like [marc_s suggested in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859160/define-column-name-dynamically-by-current-date-in-sql-server/9859567#comment12569004_9859160):
leave the query as it is, return the month names in addition and let the client display the month names in the right place.

Comment: @betite why haven't you selected this as the answer?