# SQL Server: Assign a dynamic column name using current DATENAME as column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I am using the following query to return all dates in the current month in M/D/YYYY format:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT(findetail.endtime, 'M/d/yyyy') FROM position
JOIN findetail ON position.position = findetail.position
JOIN product ON position.product = product.product
WHERE MONTH(findetail.endtime) = MONTH(GETDATE())
AND YEAR(findetail.endtime) = YEAR(GETDATE())     
ORDER BY FORMAT(findetail.endtime, 'M/d/yyyy')
```

This returns a single column with every date from the current month but the column is not named.

```
 | (No column name) |
_|__________________|_
 |     2/1/2016     |
 |     2/10/2016    |
 |     2/11/2016    |
 |     2/12/2016    |
 |     2/13/2016    |
 |        ...       |
```

For gins, I was wondering if there was a way to use the current date's `DATENAME` as the column name in my query so that it isn't hard coded? This is for OCD purposes only, it isn't accomplishing anything but I am curious if it is possible. I am using the following query to get the date name:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(GETDATE()), 0) -1)
```

returns `February`. From what I have gathered the only way to accomplish this is by using dynamic sql which I have never messed with. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The goal is to return:

```
 |     February     |
_|__________________|_
 |     2/1/2016     |
 |     2/10/2016    |
 |     2/11/2016    |
 |     2/12/2016    |
 |     2/13/2016    |
 |        ...       |
```

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL for this purpose.  The column names are well-defined for a SQL query.

Comment: You would have to use dynamic sql to do this.

Comment: Yes I realize that, but I have never used dynamic sql so I am not sure how to code this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859160/define-column-name-dynamically-by-current-date-in-sql-server

Comment: Dynamic sql just means you define your query as a string, store it in a `nvarchar(max)` variable or something, and pass it to `exec`. Because it's a string, you can generate the column name when you build the string. It's ugly though, I wouldn't do it if I didn't have to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** **UPDATED** **

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Here is what I got.

**QUERY:**

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = 'DECLARE @DateFrom DATE, @DateTo DATE;
SET @DateFrom = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1, 0)), 101); -- FIRST DAY OF PREVIOUS MONTH
SET @DateTo = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)), 101); -- LAST DAY OF CURRENT MONTH
WITH Dates AS (
    SELECT @DateFrom AS DatesInMonth
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DatesInMonth) FROM Dates WHERE DatesInMonth < @DateTo
)
SELECT FORMAT(DatesInMonth, ''M/d/yyyy'') AS '+ DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) +' FROM Dates';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

**RETURNS:**

```
 |     February     |
_|__________________|_
 |     2/1/2016     |
 |     2/2/2016     |
 |     2/3/2016     |
 |     2/4/2016     |
 |     2/5/2016     |
 |        ...       |
```

Reworked the query to order the results correctly instead of ordering by the first character, and using @JamieD77's suggestion to remove the scaler function.

Comment: Not sure you need that scaler function.. you can replace `+ @month +` in your `@sql` with `+ DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) +` and it would work the same

Comment: `DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(GETDATE()), 0) -1)` is equal to `DATENAME(MONTH, '1900-01-01' + 2 months ('1900-03-01') - 1 month ('1900-02-01'))`  which is exactly the same as `DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())`